# How to parse the extended versions of Time Zone Information Format?

Tags: timezone

The Time Zone Information Format described in [Tzif](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-murchison-tzdist-tzif-00.html#rfc.section.3) and [tzfile](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tzfile.5.html) has timezone details like daylight saving transitions.

Subsequent versions extended the original by adding a second section to the file. The first section is the 32 bit header and body, with timestamps up to 19 January, 2038 03:14:07 UTC. The second section is the 64 bit header and body, able to represent timestamps approximately 292 billion years into the future.

Is the 64 bit body a continuation of the data in the 32 bit body, or a substitute? In other words, does a 64 bit implementation read both bodies, or should it skip the first and read only the second body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 64-bit body has exactly the same data as the 32-bit body, but to more precision.

I'd expect a 64-bit implementation to just skip the 32-bit body and read the 64-bit body, although it needs to read the various counts in order to know how much data it *should* skip.

A 64-bit implementation *could* read both bodies and validate that they contain the same zones in the same order etc, but I'd expect that only to happen with tools which were specifically for diagnosing and validating the time zone data rather than working with it as part of a larger application.

Comment: Thanks very much, great answer.